# Titles, Labels, Headings, Notices, Slogans Missing Stuff

Tags: articles, ellipsis

Michael Swan in his book http://ielts-house.net/Ebook/Vocabulary/Practical%20English%20usage.pdf (page 1) writes:

---

**Titles, labels, headings, notices and slogans usually consist of short phrases,
not complete sentences. Articles are often left out, especially in the names of
buildings and instituations.**

*ROYAL HOTEL*

*SUPER CINEMA*

*INFORMATION OFFICE*

*BUS STOP*

*POLICE OUT*

*MORE MONEY FOR NURSES*

---

The question is which of this is what and what all of this would look like if it were written in a full way? As I can see

*ROYAL HOTEL* -signboard/possibly a label

*SUPER CINEMA* - signboard/possibly a label

*INFORMATION OFFICE* - signboard/possibly a label

*BUS STOP* - signboard/possibly a label

*POLICE OUT* - unknown.../possible a notice

*MORE MONEY FOR NURSES* - slogan

On the other hand, if something of this is published in a newspaper, it will become a title or a headline. So, I guess all of it can be anything of the list...

Now the full forms. The author doesn't mention any verbs or other words except for the articles that can be left out. So, the matter is in the articles and in a full way all of this should look like

**THE** *ROYAL HOTEL*

**THE** *SUPER CINEMA*

**THE** *INFORMATION OFFICE*

**THE** *BUS STOP*

**THE** *POLICE OUT*

*MORE MONEY FOR* **THE** *NURSES*

Right?

Answer (score 1):

*Royal Hotel* and *Super Cinema* are names of buildings, which obviously would have a sign on the front. We would say "*Frozen* is on at *the* Super Cinema."

*Information Office* could be described as an institution; a place provided by an organisation for the public to go. "I'll go and ask at *the* Information Office.

*Bus Stop* is obviously on a sign marking the place.

I was puzzled by *Police out* until I looked at your link and found that both the last two have exclamation marks, indicating that they are both meant to be slogans. "[There should be] or [We want] more money for [the] nurses!"

Comment: 1) So, **Royal Hotel** and **Super Cinema** = names of buildings. **Information Office** = institution. **Bus Stop** = sign. As I understand if they are used somewhere in a text they can have articles but if they are used like sign which we can see in front of ourselves they have the "no article for titles, headlines, signs..." rule. Right?
2) By the way, you are right! I didn't notice the exclamation mark! Wow! Do I have to undertsand the police example like **"[The] police [is] out!"**?

Comment: 3) As I can see we have only institutions, buildings and slogans here. Doesn't author give us any titles, headlines, labels, notices as examples?

Comment: A slogan is usually a demand for something - I suppose  _[We want] the police out [of here]!_ A book title may contain an article but isn't a complete sentence - _The history of England_. Headline - _Trump elected President_. Label - _Exercise book_. Notice - _School Rules_.

Comment: A) I think there may be three variants of **"POLICE OUT"**

1) *Police: "Keep out"!* - a phrase from the police for people to keep out

2) *Police is out.* - saying that police is out

3) *Police, keep out!* - advising the police to keep out

Can all of them be possible?
B) May the **"The history of England"** book title may also be without the article? The Trump sentence is like **"Trump [has been] elected [as a] President"**? I was told **"Bus Stop, Royal Hotel, Super Cinema etc"**. were labels too.So, everything seems to be a label...?

Comment: If "School rules" is a notice then I don't understand what "notice" means...

Comment: Perhaps that wasn't a very good example; I was thinking of a list posted on a notice board. Here are some notices https://www.bing.com/images/search?q=notice&form=HDRSC2&first=1&scenario=ImageBasicHover

Comment: 1) What about "labels"? 2) So, notice = attention, warning?

Comment: A notice is a sign or paper displayed in a public place to give information or instructions. A label is a small sign on an object to say what it is or contains - _Peanut Butter_ (on a jar). _Exercise Book_ (on a child's notebook). I wouldn't call a sign outside a hotel a label.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110150/discussion-between-kate-bunting-and-michael-azarenko).